# Cómo llamar a un job desde un command laravel

Tags: laravel, funciones

tengo el siguiente job

```
public function handle()
{
    MailMessage::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->forceDelete();
    MailTask::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->forceDelete();
    Meo::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->forceDelete();
}
```

quisiera saber cómo llamar a esta función desde un comando que hice

```
public function handle()
{
    
    $this->info('All deleted');

}
```

arriba tengo esto `use App\Jobs\MeoDataCleaner as JobMeoDataCleaner;`
gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

El job tiene su forma de llamarlo

```
    return JobMeoDataCleaner::dispatchNow();
```